# Data structure for non-blocking aggregation of Thread values?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, aggregate, nonblocking

**Background:**
I have a large thread-pool in java each process has some internal state. 
I would like to gather some global information about the states -- to do that I have an associative commutative aggregation function (e.g. sum -- mine needs to be plug-able though).

The solution needs to have a fixed memory consumption and be log-free in best case not disturbing the pool at all. So no thread should need to require a log (or enter a synchronized area) when writing to the data-structure. The aggregated value is only read after the threads are done, so I don't need an accurate value all the time. Simply collecting all values and aggregate them after the pool is done might lead to memory problems.
The values are going to be more complex datatypes so I cannot use AtomicInteger etc.

**My general Idea for the solution:**
Have a log-free collection where all threads put their updates to. I don't even need the order of the events.
If it gets to big run the aggregation function on it (compacting it) while the threads continue filling it.

**My question:**
Is there a data structure that allows for something like that or do I need to implement it from scratch? I couldn't find anything that directly matches my problem. If I have to implement from scratch what would be a good non-blocking collection class to start from?

Comment: Can you define "logfree"?

Comment: @fge possibly lock-free??

Comment: @assylias good point! Mind reviewing my answer?

Comment: @fge To be honest I'm not sure I understand the question so can't really tell if an answer makes sense or not!

Comment: @assylias AFAIU, the important point here is: "Have a logfree collection where all threads put their updates to.", which is the base point for my solution; each thread (the key of the map) has its private space (the matching value) to which it writes its update. Ensuring thread safety resumes to ensuring key/value pair creation before the thread starts; the map itself needs not be synchronized at all, as long as the "managing class" has exclusive access to it. I may be mistaken, though.

Comment: I don't see any reason to avoid using a lock.  I would hope you are spending much more time process than accumulating in this case. If not I would reconsider how you are using multiple threads.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Answer (score 1):

If the updates are infrequent (relatively speaking) and the aggregation function is fast, I would recommend aggregrating every time:

```
State myState;
AtomicReference<State> combinedState;
do
{
    State original = combinedState.get();
    State newCombined = Aggregate(original, myState);
} while(!combinedState.compareAndSet(original, newCombined));
```

Comment: The problem is that the update happens frequently and the function is rather costly. While this solution should work, I'm not sure how much it will impact the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question but I would, at first sight, suggest an `IdentityHashMap` where keys are (references to) your thread objects and values are where your thread objects write their statistics.

An `IdentityHashMap` only relies on reference equality, as such there would never be any conflict between two thread objects; you could pass a reference to that map to each thread (which would then call `.get(this)` on the map to get a reference to the collecting data structure), which would then collect the data it wants. Otherwise you could just pass a reference to the collecting data structure to the thread object.

Such a map is inherently thread safe for your use case, as long as you create the key/value pair for that thread *before* starting the thread, and because no thread object will ever modify the map anyway since they won't have a referece to it. With some management smartness you can even *remove* entries from this map, even if the map is not even thread-safe, once the thread is done with its work.

When all is done, you have a map whose values contains all the data collected.

Hope this helps... Reading the question again, in any case...

Comment: Why do you need the `IdentityHashMap`?  Thread equals (Object) is reference equality anyway.

Comment: @Gray because an `IdentityHashMap` is optimized for reference equality; I doubt OP will implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` on thread objects anyway